# SQL Questions regarding looping based on Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Newbie question here.. I want to take the results of a SELECT query, which is 1 column that contains 100's of ID's..

Using this ID, I then want to search another column in a different table for the existence of the ID and then count the number of occurrences.. The end result giving me a list of all ID's from the first query and the number of occurrences matched. How is this best achieved, I'm a little stuck on passing the results of one query to another..

I have something along the lines of

```
 SELECT id From TABLE1 
 WHERE id IN (SELECT ID from TABLE2 WHERE ID EXISTS TABLE2.COLUMNNAME)  
 group by ID
```

Thanks,
S

Comment: What have you already tried? Showing some of your queries is more useful than verbal description of them.

Comment: Show some sample data and desired output.

Comment: I have something along the lines of :                                                            SELECT id From TABLE1
    WHERE id IN (SELECT ID from TABLE2 WHERE ID EXISTS TABLE2.COLUMNNAME) 
     group by ID

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

```
select T.ID, count(T1.ID) as [Count]
from 
    (your_first_select_query_here) as T
    left outer join your_table as T1 on T1.ID = T.ID
group by T.ID
```

First you should join your first query result with your target table and then group by first result ID calculating count of IDs from target table.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need something like this

```
Select id,Count(id) AS Id_Count From Table_2 
Where id in(Select id from table_1) 
group by id
```

Comment: In fact, it outputs not quite the same result OP wants (see original requirement: "a list of **all** ID's from the first query and the number of occurrences matched"). Your query will output only those ids exists in table, so for not-existed ids it will not output `0` as count.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you want:

```
SELECT
    Table1.ID,
    COUNT(Table1.ID)
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
GROUP BY Table1.ID
```

Comment: Either I haven't explained myself that well or I can't see how any of these would work.. The ID from Table1 does not exist in Table2 as a column, so I cannot join to this Table. The ID only exists within the value or a row . It's not actually a Column within Table2.. So what I'm trying to do, Is to look inside the 'value' of a column and match the ID if it exists, then count the number of occurrences, this information is held in Table2.UserInfo - as a long string

Comment: How are these id's split in the string ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to get IDs from table2. So select from table2. For any found table2 record you want to count matching records in table1. You can do this in a subquery in your select clause:

```
select 
  id,
  (select count(*) from table1 where table1.id_table2 = table2.id)
from table2
where ...
```